# prevent controllers having same method redundancy in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Current I have three controllers that uses the exact same **authorize_journey** method (located in the controllers). Each controller also calls the exact same **before_filter :authorize_journey**. What is the best way to reduce this kind of redundancy through best-practice?

Also, how can I, if possible, stick to the fat-model-skinny-controller practice?

Comment: You shouldn't have fat models, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the authorize_journey methods are all identical, then you can move a copy to '~/app/controllers/application_controller.rb' and remove it from all the individual controllers.

The before_filters can all remain as they are.

Of course, if the methods are not identical, you may require some refactoring to generalize it further.   If you post the code, we can comment further.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use it in the `application_controller.rb`.

Move the `authorize_journey` method to `application_controller`.

Say if you have 4 controllers and you need the `before_filter` in 3 controller. Then you can define the `before_filter :authorize_journey` in the the `application_controller` and use:

```
skip_before_filter :authorize_journey
```

in the 4th controller where you don't want the `before_filter`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding the method to a concern and include them in the controllers that requires the authorize_journey before_filter.

Code for concern will be:

```
# controllers/concerns/authorize_journery.rb
module AuthorizeJourney
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_filter :authorize_journey
  end

  protected

  def authorize_journey
    # Code goes here
  end

end
```

Now in the controllers, include the AuthorizeJourney module.

```
# controllers/examples_controller.rb
class ExamplesController < ApplicationController
  include AuthorizeJourney

  # Code goes here
end
```

Comment: @user3277633 I would suggest using concerns rather than moving the code to application_controller.